# Start/Stop Prometheus Server/AlertManager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, systemctl

Is there anyway to Start/Stop Prometheus Server/AlertManager and to run continuously in the backend without using systemctl commands .

Thank You.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.